# How to find min and max time in Chat log conversation using pandas for calculating duration?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

Want to calculate the duration of each ID and to write in the separate Columns

```
ID  Ques   Time  Expected output
----------------------------------
11   Hi    11.21   1min
11   Hello 11.22
13   hey   12.11   10mins   
13   what  12.22
14   so    01.01   2mins
14   ok    01.03 
----------------------------------
```

Tried so far -

```
First_last_cover = English_Logs['Date'].agg(['min','max'])
print ("First Conversation and Last Conversation of the month", First_last_cover)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please paste formatted data, not images - makes it hard to copy. Please post expected output as well

Comment: Thanks Vivek. Am trying to add tables but i couldn't add.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is step by step. `diff_mins` column is the desired output -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/FGB3140/Desktop/sample.csv')

df['Time_parsed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H.%M')
df['Time_parsed_shifted'] = df['Time_parsed'].shift(1)
df['diff'] = df['Time_parsed']-df['Time_parsed_shifted']
df['diff_mins'] = df['diff'].dt.seconds / 60
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
ID   Ques   Time         Time_parsed Time_parsed_shifted     diff  \
0  11     Hi  11.21 1900-01-01 11:21:00                 NaT      NaT   
1  11  Hello  11.22 1900-01-01 11:22:00 1900-01-01 11:21:00 00:01:00   
2  13    hey  12.11 1900-01-01 12:11:00 1900-01-01 11:22:00 00:49:00   
3  14   what  12.22 1900-01-01 12:22:00 1900-01-01 12:11:00 00:11:00   

   diff_mins  
0        NaN  
1        1.0  
2       49.0  
3       11.0
```

**Explanation**

1. Parse the `Time` column
2. Use `.shift()` to shift the column down a row - `Time_parsed_shifted`
3. Take the difference in time
4. Represent that difference in minutes

Comment: Thank for the help. Am looking for to find conversation period time only each ID. Ex - For ID-11 time is 1 min , ID - 13 0 mins, ID -14 - 0 mins

Comment: `groupby()` the ID first and then do these steps

Comment: groupby it not giving what i expected.Kindly recheck the question Mr.Vivek.It will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Assumption made:

1. The file contains time for eachID and Timemin and TimeMax is calculated.
   The bellow code explains how to calculate the diff in the time and add as a new row

> Assuming the ***data*** contains the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil.parser
```

## Add a coulmn with duration calculating the time diffrence.

```
data['duration'] = data.apply(lambda x :(dateutil.parser.parse(x['TimeMax'])-dateutil.parser.parse(x['Timemin'])).total_seconds() , axis=1)
```